# PHP: include 'nav.php' with path to logo in other folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

So I have `nav.php`:

```
<div>
   <!-- and a lot of more code here so thats why i want write it once and include into all pages in main folder but also subfolders
   <img src="logo.png">
 </div>
```

And main folder looks like that:

- nav.php
- logo.png
- index.php
- subfolder with `secondpage.php`

In the `index.php` and all pages in main folder I did it like this:

```
<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>
```

In the `secondpage.php` in subfolder I did it this way:

```
<?php include '../nav.php'; ?>
```

But then logo don't appear because of course the path is wrong, it should be "../logo.png"

my solutions is:

1. Make `nav.php` for `subfolders` in main folder with correct path
2. Copy `nav.php` to every subfolder and link it like in main

but I don't think any of these solutions are acceptable if I have 10 subfolders?

Comment: try `<img src="/logo.png">`

Comment: So it will search for any depth subfolder?

Comment: it will use the `logo.png` from the root of your web folder from whatever depth you include `nav.php`

Comment: Unfortunately dont work...

Comment: what is not working? is your main folder the web root folder?

Comment: Its in htdocs/mysite/index.php but I just found out that / works in CSS but not PHP because root in server is way much deeper than our index.php is - read this https://css-tricks.com/php-include-from-root/

Comment: You can try to use if/else condition in your nav.php, which changes the src according to which file it has been included in (more like which level of directory)

Comment: Thats not efficient too

Comment: if `<img src="logo.png">` works from your `index.php` then `<img src="/logo.png">` should work from any sub folder.

Comment: but it really do not in xampp

Answer (score 1):

Add a global variable $site_root.
In your project initialization, set that to the root directory of your project.
I suggest storing all images, like logos in a separate directory. ie: /img

Then you can create your links in any page like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $site_root; ?>/img/logo.png">
```